# Somente uma classe pode instanciar outra classe, como fazer isso?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Olá, estou fazendo um UML sobre um exercício, porém não consigo fazer uma parte dele.

O exercício diz que somente a classe administrador pode criar outro colaborador, eu queria saber como poderia implementar isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo do que fiz até agora abaixo:

*CLASSE Funcionario*

```
package com.trabalho1;

public abstract class Funcionario {

    protected String nome;
    protected String cpf;

    public Funcionario(String nome, String cpf){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

}
```

*CLASSE Administrador*

```
package com.trabalho1;

public class Administrador extends Funcionario{

    public Administrador(String nome, String cpf) {
        super(nome, cpf);
    }
}
```

*CLASSE Colaborador*

```
package com.trabalho1;

public abstract class Colaborador extends Funcionario{

    public Colaborador(String nome, String cpf) {
        super(nome, cpf);
    }

}
```

*CLASSE Entregador*

```
package com.trabalho1;

public class Entregador extends Colaborador{

    public Entregador(String nome, String cpf) {
        super(nome, cpf);
    }

}
```

Comment: Seria [**isso**](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-enable-only-one-Java-class-to-instantiate-objects-of-another-class) o que vc procura?

Comment: Não consegui fazer com este método.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se somente um `Administrador` pode criar um `Colaborador`, isso significa que ninguém mais pode criá-lo, ou seja, seus construtores não podem ser públicos. Remova o `public` dos construtores de `Colaborador` e de suas subclasses:

```
public abstract class Colaborador extends Funcionario {
    // construtor sem "public"
    Colaborador(String nome, String cpf) {
        super(nome, cpf);
    }
}

public class Entregador extends Colaborador {
    // construtor sem "public"
    Entregador(String nome, String cpf) {
        super(nome, cpf);
    }
}
```

Deixando assim, somente classes dentro do mesmo pacote "enxergam" os construtores. E como o `Administrador` é o único que pode criar estas classes e ele está no mesmo pacote (`com.trabalho1`), é exatamente isso que precisamos.

Sendo assim, o único ponto em que um `Colaborador` pode ser criado é dentro das classes que estão no mesmo pacote - e `Administrador` é uma delas. E se só o `Administrador` pode criar estas classes, então você cria um método público nesta classe, que será responsável por criar colaboradores.

Além disso, `Colaborador` é uma classe abstrata, e não é possível instanciá-la. Só podemos instanciar suas subclasses. Então um modo de fazer seria ter um método que recebesse o tipo de colaborador a ser instanciado, além das informações necessárias para construí-lo (no caso, o nome e CPF).

No exemplo abaixo estou usando um `int` como o tipo de colaborador, mas nesses casos eu prefiro usar um `enum` (como eu não sei se você já conhece `enum`, vou deixar o exemplo com `int` primeiro):

```
public class Administrador extends Funcionario {
    public Colaborador criaColaborador(int tipo, String nomeColaborador, String cpfColaborador) {
        if (tipo == 1) {
            return new Entregador(nomeColaborador, cpfColaborador);
        } else if (tipo == 2) {
            // retorna outro tipo de colaborador (Secretaria, Gerente, etc)
        }
        // vários if's, para cada tipo de colaborador

        // tipo desconhecido, retorna null (ou algum valor default)? lança exception? você decide
        return null;
    }
}
```

Caso você já conheça `enum`, fica assim:

```
public enum TipoColaborador {
    SECRETARIA, GERENTE_VENDA, ENTREGADOR;
}

public class Administrador extends Funcionario {
    public Colaborador criaColaborador(TipoColaborador tipo, String nomeColaborador, String cpfColaborador) {
        if (tipo == TipoColaborador.ENTREGADOR) {
            return new Entregador(nomeColaborador, cpfColaborador);
        } else if (tipo == TipoColaborador.GERENTE_VENDA) {
            // retorna outro tipo de colaborador (Secretaria, Gerente, etc)
        }
        // vários if's, para cada tipo de colaborador

        // retorna null (ou algum valor default)? lança exception? você decide
        return null;
    }
}
```

Eu prefiro usar `enum` porque isso deixa claro quais valores podem ser passados no tipo. Se eu uso `int`, posso passar sem querer algum número qualquer que nada tem a ver com o tipo, por exemplo.

Lembrando que esta é apenas **uma** forma de fazer. Também é possível ter um método para cada tipo (`criarEntregador`, `criarSecretaria`, etc), usar `Map` para mapear os tipos e as respectivas classes (`Map<TipoColaborador, Class<? extends Colaborador>>`), entre outras (além do óbvio "usar `switch` em vez de `if`", caso você já conheça).

Mas a ideia geral para o seu problema é essa. Ao não deixar a classe ter construtores públicos, você limita e controla quem pode criar instâncias dela. No caso, o único lugar em que esses construtores são chamados é no método público que está em `Administrador`, o que significa que somente esta classe pode criar instâncias de `Colaborador`.

Para criar suas instâncias, ficaria assim:

```
Administrador admin = new Administrador("Admin", "12345678909");
Colaborador col = admin.criaColaborador(TipoColaborador.ENTREGADOR, "Fulano de Tal", "11122233396");
```

Comment: :), funcionou, porém como sou leigo ainda no java veio outro problema. Como referenciar esse objeto que acabei de criar na memória? Pois usarei ele em outras classes.

Comment: @WesleyBelizario Editei a resposta, adicionei um exemplo no final

Answer (score 1):

Quando você for fazer a implementação do cadastro de colaborador (caso queira implementar essa restrição na funcionalidade), você na classe que realiza o cadastro irá verificar se o Funcionário que está logado no sistema é do tipo Administrador! Caso ele atenda a condição você salva o colaborador, caso contrário lança uma exceção informando que o usuário não tem permissão para realizar essa ação no sistema.

A outra forma de resolver esse problema é mostrando a opção no menu para o cadastro de colaborador se ele for do tipo Administrador (terá que fazer essa verificação no login do sistema), antes de mostrar a tela com as opções. Assim, quando ele realizar o login você saberá quais opções estão disponíveis para este funcionário.

Comment: Este é um exercício, e no caso, eu teria que usar classes abstratas, herança ou sei lá. Como se trata de um exercício de POO básico eu queria achar uma forma simples para este problema.

Comment: A herança bem como a composição são um dos pilares da orientação a objetos, assim, para realizar o exercício da forma correta você necessariamente precisa utilizar os conceitos do paradigma.